# What happened between Yennefer, Triss and Geralt - Endgame

Tags: the-witcher-3

I just finished The Witcher 3 yesterday and noticed that something happened between Yennefer and Triss (and maybe Geralt?).

While Geralt and the others were preparing for the fight against

> Imlerith the "Endboss"

Triss and Yennefer one night were sitting next to Geralt to wake them up and to wispher him a little "offer". As Geralt went there he found Triss and Yennefer, both in underwear. However as he thought the action would go on the two Girls wear him handcuff and just went away.

A little later in the game as Geralt talked to Yennefer again and ask her if she and Triss had fun and what they talked about the time after, Yennefer answered something like

> We talked about anything but about Geralt of Rivia, Triss and I are no longer interested in you.

My question here: What just happened? I think nothing special happened after Geralt and Yennefer

> broke the curse of the djin and Yennefer still loves Geralt

so why is she so cold now?

Is there a way to prevent this things happen?

Comment: Is this fan fiction?

Comment: No that just happens ingame

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like the ending where Geralt has attempted to tell both Triss and Yennefer that he loves them.

Turns out, they're not a fan of you trying to seduce both of them. This is seemingly communicated off-camera, and results in the scenario you mention above, and with neither of them being interesting in continuing a relationship with Geralt.

Comment: I know what you mean but all my answers through the game were Yennefer sided.. but however it seems like there're different ends even with triss and yennefer, good to know thanks

Comment: From what I remember, there are two points that you have to actively "choose" Yennefer. You also have to have seen Triss leave on the ship.

Comment: Oh jeah well I remember and she did not go with the ship, maybe there's the point

Comment: Getting Triss not to go with the ship is not easy and requires pursuing a relationship with her at every point possible as well as straight out telling her you love her. It's not that suprising.

Comment: Yeah you're right, i just forgot about that part of the story^^

Comment: I don't think the above is the completely correct, I didn't tell Triss I 'loved' her, (I choose the middle option, 'lets give it another shot' or words to that effect) and she still stayed. I then romanced Yen and ended up with her at the end but I missed the infamous unicorn scene somehow. :-/

Answer (score -1):

In fact this coolness of Yennefer regarding Triss is much more about the books of The Witcher than about the games. Geralt and Yennefer made a commitment and lived together when one day Triss "doped" him and had sex with him. Yennefer was very angry about the betrayal coming from a close friend and "boyfriend" and it took years to forgive them. Still, Yennefer still has some grief and is kind of cool about Geralt and Triss

Comment: To understand the games of The Witcher I highly recommend you read the nine books in the series. It gets you deeper into the relationship between the characters.

Comment: This answer seems irrelevant.  OP was asking about Triss' and Yennefer's treatment of _Geralt_, not Triss.  If anything, it sounds like Triss and Yennefer aren't so cold to each other in the narrative here; and both are cold to Geralt.

Comment: Oh, yes, now I get it. Sorry, it's because I speak another language, sometimes I make some translation mistakes. Just disregard.